# live data is not returning value in fragment second time in android

Tags: android

this code in view model :

```
 override fun onSuccessVideoList(data: LIST) {
            val listOfData = arrayListOf<RoveR3NtkVideoEntities>()
            if (data.allFile == null){
                listOfData.add(RoveR3NtkVideoEntities())
                stateLiveData.postValue(CameraR3NtkProStatus.VideoSuccessData(listOfData))
            }
            data?.allFile?.let { it1 ->
                it1.forEach {
                    val startTime = splitTime(it.file.name.split("_")[3])
                    val endTime = it.file.time.split(" ")[1]
                    val duration = durationVideo(endTime, startTime)
                    listOfData.add(
                        RoveR3NtkVideoEntities(
                            name = it.file.name,
                            size = getSize(it.file.size),
                            date = it.file.time.split(" ")[0],
                            path = it.file.fpath,
                            endTime = endTime,
                            startTime = startTime,
                            duration = duration
                        )
                    )
                }
                stateLiveData.value = CameraR3NtkProStatus.VideoSuccessData(listOfData)
    
            }
    
        }
```

this code which i oberving in fragment

```
private fun getR3ConnectedInDashCameFragment(state: BaseViewModel.CameraR3NtkProStatus) {
        when (state) {
            is BaseViewModel.CameraR3NtkProStatus.VideoSuccessData -> {
                notConnectedWidget.hide()
                roveR3NtkDashCameWidget.show()
                customLoader.hide()
                roveR3NtkDashCameWidget.setContent(state.videoList)
            }
            else -> {}
        }
    }
```

This is my code i am trying to observer value in fragment when we have some data then i am getting call back in fragment in live data VideoSuccessData but when we are getting null condition then in view model i am getting call back but in fragment  stateLiveData is not observing  please help me where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

try

> stateLiveData.postValue(...)

instead of

> stateLiveData.value = ...